# LED pins high and low at the same time?

Tags: arduino

Can someone explain me why are they using the same variable "i" to determine which pins are high. 
I understood everything except the function block at barGraphDisplay. Like how can you set one pin at high and all the rest at low with only "i" ? The way I see it, the function chooses only one position of the array and evaluates it.

[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvqRs.png)
[image]

[Code Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBAsx.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, the variable i in barGraphDisplay is scoped to the function, so the variable i in loop() is not relevant.

Second, the call to digitalWrite is inside a for loop, so i isn't just one number, it's all values in ledCount.  Additionally, it's inside an if / else block, so if `i == ledOn` then the LED is set to HIGH, otherwise LOW.  But the same pin (denoted by the value of i) is never set to both states.